# Django how to prevent patched method running when created in super class

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a model with a post-save method that I don’t want to run in test:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.post_save_method()

    def post_save_method(self):
        print("oh no!")
        return "real value"
```

If I make a normal test everything works as I would expect. I can patch the method, and see that I get the mocked return value, and that the `post_save_method` does not run (nothing is printed from this method to the console):

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import MyModel
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestMakeObjectNormally(TestCase):

    @patch.object(MyModel, 'post_save_method')
    def test_something(self, post_save_mock):
        post_save_mock.return_value = "mocked value"
        my_model = MyModel.objects.create()
        print(my_model.post_save_method())
```

But the way the tests are set up is that the instance is created in a superclass. Following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/morenoh149/c9e985c72a0f7d929866dd5c4b3d8a41) I tried to patch at a class level:

```py
class BaseTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_model = MyModel.objects.create()

@patch.object(MyModel, 'post_save_method')
class TestMakeObjectInSuper(BaseTest):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def test_something(self, post_save_mock):
        post_save_mock.return_value = "mocked value"
        print(self.my_model.post_save_method())
```

This works in that the `post_save_method` return value is the mocked one, but unfortunately I can see that the method is running (“oh no!” is printed to the console).

(I also tried patching both `setUp()` methods and the base class)

Any advice appreciated!